# Parent pom and maven goals for only war projects

Tags: maven

I have a multi module maven project. It has 5 module and 2 of them are web projects.

I want to customize my plugins to be run at only war projects. I mean at parent pom level I would like to trigger my goals and only my war projects will be affected. Is there any way for it?

As a result of this, I will not have duplicated configurations at my war projects pom.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can build a war parent pom (where your war projects are inheriting from) and a general parent pom (where everyone else is inheriting from).

```
        general parent
          /      \   \
   war parent     \   \
      /  \         \   \  
 war1    war2  other1  other2
```

For building you may have a seperate build pom, having all the above as modules.

HTH

Comment: +1 If you need to have a parent POM for all your WAR modules *across projects*, then you are doomed. Some tricks are possible with profiles, but it doesn't allow as much as a inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem numerous times and I have come to the conclusion that the best solution is as follows:

```
cool-master
|-+ parents
| |- cool-parent
| |- cool-parent-web
|
|- module1
|- module2
|- module3
|- module-web1
|- module-web2
```

In the above example there are three types of modules:

- parent POM-s (`cool-parent`, `cool-parent-web`)
- non-web aps (extending `cool-parent`)
- webapps (extending `cool-parent-web`)

In the parents you can define settings which are specific for the different types of modules. For example in the `cool-parent` define non-webapp related stuff, wheres in the `cool-parent-web` you can have all the fancy stuff like `maven-war-plugin`, `jetty-maven-plugin`, etc. I generally have the `cool-parent-web` extend the `cool-parent` in order to avoid having to duplicate dependencies, plugins settings and etc.

In the `cool-parent-web` define a `<pluginManagement/>` section and set up all the stuff for your plugins and then just use them across your web modules.